# How to print words who contains two "z" or two "w" (bash)

Tags: shell, grep

i'm trying to print words in /usr/share/dict/words who contains two "w" or two "z". It doesn't matter where are the "w" or the "z" in the word.
I've tried this but it doesn't work properly :

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep ".+([wz]).+\1"
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep ".*([wz]).*\1"
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep "z{2}|w{2}"
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep "z.*z|w.*w"
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep "z.?z|w.?w"
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep "z[^z].*z|w[^w].*w"
```

Comment: If you have a regex, you'd want to use egrep

Comment: I disagree with the close-voters and wish they would provide a more complete explanation than a perfunctory button-click.

Comment: Do you want only `"contains two "w" or two "z"` or `"contains two (or more) "w" or two (or more)  "z"`? (you were close with `grep "z.*z|w.*w"` which would work as `grep 'z.*z\|w.*w'`)

Comment: only "contains two "w" or two "z" :  
"pizza" OK
"pizzazz" not OK
"awkward" OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see words with at least 2 ws or 2 zs you can do:

```
egrep "(z.*z|w.*w)" /usr/share/dict/words
```

**Explanation**: Matches any line that contains at least 2 zs or at least 2 ws

To see words that have *exactly* 2 ws or zs you can do:

```
egrep "^([^z]*z[^z]*z[^z]*|[^w]*w[^w]*w[^w]*)$" /usr/share/dict/words
```

**Explanation**: Matches any line that starts with 0 or more non z/w letters, followed by a z/w, followed by zero or more non z/w letters, followed by a z/w and another set of zero or more non z/w letters. In short, makes sure there are exactly 2 of zs or ws.

Comment: Your solution works well thank you for your explanation ;)

Answer (score 2):

With -E flag for ERE support:

```
grep -E 'w.*w|z.*z' /usr/share/dict/words
grep -E '([wz]).*\1' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Concerning the second one, some implementations may not support backreferences in an ERE, so don't rely on it, don't expect it to work everywhere.

Comment: A BRE of `grep 'z.*z\|w.*w'` will also do `:)`

Comment: As a bit of trivia, in my `/usr/share/dict/american` there are `1546` words containing either 2 `'w'` or 2 `'z'` `"Zyzzyva /ˈzɪzɪvə/ is a genus of tropical American weevils often found in association with palms. It is a snouted beetle."` `:)`

Comment: @DavidCRankin Alternation in BREs is a GNU extension. If portability matters, needs the ERE version.

Answer (score 1):

To match words with *exactly* two w's or z's (not three or more), you could use:

```
grep -E '^[^w]*w[^w]*w[^w]*$|^[^z]*z[^z]*z[^z]*$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` how about:

```
awk 'gsub("w", "&") >= 2 || gsub("z", "&") >= 2' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: Should be `>= 2` on both counts. (unless he want just 2 -- unclear)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your comment. I did wonder which should be proper. Now I agree using `>=` would be safer. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I added a comment under the original question requesting clarification. I suspect they want two or more, but it isn't outside the realm of possibility they mean exactly two. They can choose I guess.

Comment: it's exactly two. 
Works well if i change `>=` by `==`
Thanks.

Comment: @Dj-liwood Thanks for the feedback. It's my pleasure if my answer is readable enough so you can modify it according to the requirements. BR.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find the "two distinct expressions" approach a bit more readable:

```
$ grep -e 'z.*z' -e 'w.*w' /usr/share/dict/words | head
abuzz
adazzle
Albizzia
amidoazobenzene
amidoazobenzol
aminoazobenzene
arrowweed
arrowwood
arrowworm
athwarthawse
```